Capacitor lifetime analysis - maximum ripple current for a traction inverter 48 V 10 kW
I am trying to design the power stage for a 48 V 10 kW traction inverter with a 152 Arms current. I came across a great article to design the DC link capacitance here. Based on this, I can assume a capacitor ripple current of roughly 0.55x = ~80 A. Typically at 48 V, capacitors rated up to 63 V can handle max ripple current of 3 A per capacitor. Based on this one would need 80/3 = 26–27 capacitors which is way too much. Am I missing something?
Most of the reference designs I see use much lower number of capacitors, like 7-8 max with a 3 A ripple per capacitor. Do I need to consider lifetime analysis to understand how much abuse a capacitor can handle? If yes, could you please give an idea of how to do this calculation please? Many thanks in advance.

The calculation seems reasonable. What's "way too much" about it? What frequency is this at, have you considered all types of capacitor? -- Or changing the frequency to make more compact types feasible?

You should read the article you linked more carefully as it provides you with an answer.

The ripple current will cause heating. Maximum limits are based on some assumed life and ambient temperature. They may or may not be conservative for your application. Generally you can roughly assume the capacitor life span halves for every 10°C increase of core temperature above the reference temperature (and doubles for every 10°C below).
There seem to be plenty  of capacitors designed for this kind of service (eg. 13mF with 10A ripple current rating  at kHz).
Of course they're not as cheap as general purpose electrolytic capacitors.
You can find a detailed analysis of capacitor life from CDE here, which supports the above-mentioned relationship with an additional operating voltage correction factor.
